# Is there a log of auto-updated apps?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

iOS 7 has a new auto-update apps feature.  When it's enabled, you don't have to manually go into the App Store app and download updates for your installed apps.  However, I want to be able to find out what apps have been updated recently, and the App Store app just has a 'all your apps are updated' message on the Update tab.

Is there a log somewhere that lists recently-updated apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Store should show a list of apps in the Update tab that have been updated, with details such as when it was updated, the changelog and a button to open the app.

[image: App Store Updates Tab]

Comment: I finally got my first batch of post-iOS 7 upgrade app updates, and I see this on my iPhone now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blue dot next to the app name for any app that has been updated, or downloaded, and has not been started since that update/download.  This allows you to keep track of what is updating.  I'm sure on a jailbroken machine (when a jailbreak is available) you can list IPAs by modified date to get a list you could then use for some other purpose.